# automatic purchases

Tags: api, web-applications, e-commerce

Is it possible to make automatic purchases on websites (example: Amazon)?
If so, what information would be required (FName, LName, Billing Address, CC#)?
And Finally Where should I look for these possible solutions?

Someone asked if this is possible, I am looking to research any possibility of this even being remotely possible.

Comment: This seems too broad to really answer, Lucas but in general you're going to need to work through the API of whatever site you're targeting. You could write a sophisticated scraper/response agent to push through a site's workflow from page to page but it would be specific to each site and the risk of something bad happening when they changed their interface could be very great. You could end up ordering the incorrect item, exposing sensitive data, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, This is the issues I see with the idea as well. I feel that to make this service very broad it would need a lot of work with many e-commerce web platform API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to have a fully automatic (one click) payment through Amazon or any other market like that. In order for the purchaser to stay safe, they need to be able to log into amazon (or google, etc) directly.

Comment: exactly, I don't see a real plausible way to automatically act as a user, and even if so, as [Carth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/946922/carth) mention in the above comment, there is much room for error.